# NVDA 508 Compliance - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nvda

I have an application built on Ruby on Rails.
Anyone got any idea on how to make a web application NVDA 508 compliant.
I have read different articles, but not getting exact information on steps needed to do this.
Anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might get more answers over at User Experience.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old and my answer is no specific, but think it should be said.  508 Compliance should not be about any one specific (Assistive technology) AT.  If your site adheres to the Section 508 guidelines NVDA should be functional.  If you adhere to the [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) and section 508 guideline you should not have any issues with any AT.